# Prevent XSS/Cross site scripting vulnerability - request.getParameter() in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, security, jsp, xss

I am looking to remediate the JSP page which has multiple variable with request.getParameter(). Can you please suggest whats the replacement for this.

```
 <%
if(appStatusId == AppCon.DECLINED) {
                String VPC = request.getParameter(constants.PRODUCT_CODE);
        %>


String Make = request.getParameter(constants.VEH_MAKE);

String NewUsed = request.getParameter(constants.VEH_NEWUSED);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When handling untrusted user input (like the values from request.getParameter() you should always escape the input before displaying it.

Use a utility class like [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) (from [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/)) to escape the data instead of escaping it by your own.

For your example it would look like this:

```
String myVariable = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(request.getParameter("myParameter")
```

You can find background information about escaping at the OWASP website [C4: Encode and Escape Data](https://owasp.org/www-project-proactive-controls/v3/en/c4-encode-escape-data)

Comment: Thank you this worked